# Random variable for deterministic experiment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

This might be a very basic question. Consider a deterministic variable $X \in \mathbb{Z}$. The deterministic variable $Y$ is a function of $X$ such that $Y=f(X)$. Now $n$ deterministic experiments are performed with known $n$ values of $ X$ to generate $n$ values for $Y$. Is the notion of random variable valid to describe the outcomes of such an experiment since all experiments are deterministic? Does the notion of deterministic random variable hold when the outcomes of the experiments are perfectly predictable?

Regards.

Comment: what "deterministic" means here? that any variation in the results will be due to noise or error?

Comment: Deterministic is used to denote that the outcome of the experiment can be predicted with absolute surety. No randomness is involved in the outcome of the experiment, but randomness is in the choice of various values of $X$ .

Answer (score 1):

The onliest way to understand "deterministic variable" and "deterministic random variable" is to suppose that this variables are constants.

Every constant is a random variable by defintion of a random variable. So in some sense you may suppose that a constant is a  "deterministic random variable". But this approach is useless.

Comment: But I thought the word "random" in random variable came from the fact that it a real valued function of sample space of random experiment (experiments with more than 1 outcome). So what happens if the experiment is deterministic and sample space is a singleton set, can you call it a "random" variable?

Comment: @William A random variable is a measurable function on corresponding space. Hence constant is a random variable.

Comment: But aren't random variables associated with random experiments only? So deterministic experiments can have random variables defined on their sample space...?

Comment: @William Do you speak about random variables in the context of probability theory? If yes, then they are measurable functions (and hence constants are random variables), if no, than what is the context?